# less compile with rhino error: org.lesscss.LessException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function bind in object

Tags: gradle, rhino

I got this error when I try to use less-rhino to compile less to css using gradle's lesscss plugin.
I tried with different java versions, different rhino versions, even tried to upgrade my os to OS X Yosemite. Nothing helps.
Using lessc command line (npm) works.

```
org.lesscss.LessException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function bind in object
  function _math(fn, unit, n) {
      if (!(n instanceof tree.Dimension)) {
          throw {type:"Argument", message:"argument must be a number"};
      }
      if (unit == null) {
          unit = n.unit;
      } else {
          n = n.unify();
      }
      return new (tree.Dimension)(fn(parseFloat(n.value)), unit);
  }
  . (jar:file:.../lesscss-1.7.0.1.1.jar!/META-INF/less-rhino-1.7.0.js#2926)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally i've got an answer:

Have to remove the old

`/Library/Java/Extensions/js.jar`

file, as it contains `rhino 1.7 R2`

(somehow it is stronger than the version on your classpath)

Answer (score 0):

I ran dependency:tree and found two maven versions so excluded the older.

`<exclusion>
   <artifactId>js</artifactId>
   <groupId>rhino</groupId>
</exclusion>`